# Select only day and month from bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-4

I need to select only day and month from bootstrap datepicker. I have try **viewMode**,**minViewMode** like attributes used but still I am not getting success.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Date" id="Date" />
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Date').datepicker({
    //dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    format: 'dd-mm',
    viewMode: 'days',
    minViewMode: 'days',        
    orientation: "bottom left",
    container: "#date-from-container",
    startDate: new Date()
}).on("changeDate", function (e) {        
});
});
```

can you please help me how can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `maxViewMode` instead of `minViewMode`. `startView` mentions the mode at which the datepicker is opened. 0-days(default), 1-months, 2-years, 3-decades, 4-centuries.

To be simple,

1. If you need to configure **from a mode** use : `minViewMode`.
2. If you need to configure **to a mode** use : `maxViewMode`.

```js
$.fn.datepicker.dates.en.titleFormat="MM";
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); 
    date_input.datepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm',
      autoclose: true,
      startView: 1,
      maxViewMode: "months",
      orientation: "bottom left",
    })
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css');
.datepicker table tr td.disabled,
.datepicker table tr td.disabled:hover {
  color: #b90000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<input name="date">
```

To update the title format, set

`$.fn.datepicker.dates.en.titleFormat="MM";`. `en` denotes `English` language.

This may vary if a different language is used in the datepicker. Bootstrap supports the language tags specified in [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/).

For tag reference, [IETF Language Tag List](https://gist.github.com/traysr/2001377)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot This is a working for me. but how can I hide year?? I don't want to a year in the calendar? so it's possible to hide year see and after click on next and month is December then don't go then January 2019. So it's possible??can you please help me

Comment: @Edit Updated the answer. Hope you got your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much finally I got a perfect answer from your side.. Thanks a lot!!!!!